# Ruby on Rails - Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, ftp

I have a process that fetches a flat file from a mainframe via FTP. This usually works fine for some files. In others, I get: `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

That's using `Net::FTP's` `gettextfile` method.
Here is my code:

```
def find_file( position, value ) # => Value = CLKDRP03.txt, Forget the variable Position

    ftp = Net::FTP.new('IP') # => status 200
    ftp.login('user','pass') # => True

    files = ftp.list('*' + value + '*') # => Obtain the file

    if files[0] != nil

      str_file = files[0].split(" ").last # => Obtain the name of the file. In this case CLKDRP03.txt

      ftp.gettextfile(str_file,'data/input/' + str_file) # => ERROR!, str_file = CLKDRP03.txt
      # => data/input is the path where I put the files from FTP.
      return str_file

    else  
      return false
    end

end
```

If I comment the line of `ftp.gettextfile`, the error keeps coming.

Thanks in advance! Sorry for my english.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905268/ruby-1-9-netftp-encodingundefinedconversionerror

Comment: what line is the exception actually being raised from? Look at the exception trace, and find the line in your source file above that is actually included.  is it the line `files = ftp.list('*' + value + '*')`?

Comment: since people are upvoting my answer you can mark my respons as correct maybe ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For anybody that are coming here from google this is how I fixed my encoding error.

right before you declare of open your file add this code

```
.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

so before you declare the file to a variable like this :

```
csv_file = params[:file].read.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

Hope this will help some since I had this problem for a long time, but now it works yay!

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I've been struggling with this error for a while and this fixed it.

Comment: yeah no problem, same here, I tried to encode it after, but when I refactor my code I noticed that I always tried to encode it after, but never before I assigned it to a variable. Glad it helped you

Comment: Also useful to know, check the default encoding for external things with `Encoding.default_external` and set it to UTF-8 (if that is what you are primarially dealing with) `Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8`. I had a similar problem but with something in a gem, so I couldn't force_encoding too easily.

Comment: I had the same problem, except that the occasional encoding errors was on file write.  The fix for this case is `file.write(str.force_encoding("UTF-8"))`